# First letter disappears on Ajax Toolkit AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

My CompletionInterval is 100 and MinimumPrefixLength is 1. Sometimes after typing one letter that I know has completions, like 'a', after roughly one second, maybe less (but 1 second is a specified time), that initial 'a' disappears. When I type another one, I get a list of completions? Does anyone know what is going on here? I'm using v7.0607 of the  AjaxControlToolkit that brings v1.4.6 of the HtmlAgilityPack with it.

My `AutoCompleteExtender` and associates look like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="autoCompleteHidden" OnValueChanged="autoCompleteHidden_ValueChanged" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchField" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtSearchField"
    ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetVisitors" Enabled="False" CompletionInterval="100"
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionSetCount="30" OnClientItemSelected="OnAutoCompleteSelected"
    CompletionListCssClass="CompletionList" CompletionListItemCssClass="CompletionListItem" 
    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="CompletionListHighlightedItem">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

***NOTE:*** `Enabled` is set to `True` before this control group is used and back to `False` afterwards. That is NOT the problem.

The accompanying function script, below, works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnAutoCompleteSelected(source, eventArgs) {
        $("#autoCompleteHidden").val(eventArgs._text);
        __doPostBack("autoCompleteHidden", "");
    }
</script>
```

That script triggers the following code-behind handler that fetches the details for the selected visitor. It also works fine:

```
protected void autoCompleteHidden_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myVisitorObj = new XTime.OL.VisitorObj();
    myVisitorObj = XTime.BL.myVisitor.SelectVisitorByFullName(autoCompleteHidden.Value);
    if (myVisitorObj.MST_SQ != 0)
    {
        XTime.XTimeVariables.VisitorObj = myVisitorObj;
    }
    ddlSearchBy.SelectedIndex = 0;
    AutoCompleteExtender1.Enabled = false;

    //Need to reload page for Sessions variable to change
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show the markup of your AutoCompleteExtender, and the web service method that returns results.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Code added as requested.

Comment: I wonder - do you have some CSS that's maybe covering up your TextBox when you have no resuts yet (CSS that's being applied to CompletionList or CompletionListItem). Also, I don't think it will fetch results untl you have *more* characters than the minimum prefix length. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Thanks! I have never set the `MinimumPrefixLength` below 1, but even if it's 2 or 3 and you type 2 or 3 letters, they often disappear. It doesn't look like the CSS does anything, but I'll check, thanks.

Comment: It's most like that some javascript did not load. Can you open a browser debugger and watch, what's happen? I think it may be some javascript not loaded when you try to type 'a' in some cases.